# this is showing data json type from query database but can't show chart on page

Tags: json, codeigniter, highcharts, postgresql-9.2

this is showing data json type from query database but can't show chart on page. what the problem?

The first image shows the results of a database query that I've already done[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SxW4.png)
whereas the second graphic image display json, but do not appear in my web page][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZGfe.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var options = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'pendapatan',
                            type: 'line'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'PENDAPATAN DAN PENGELUARAN'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Source: Data pendapatan dan pengeluaran harian'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: []
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Rupiah'
                            }
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            line: {
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true
                                },
                                enableMouseTracking: false
                            }
                        },
                        series: []
                    }
                $.getJSON("home/dashboard/show_pendapatan_pengeluaran", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
                </script>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the JS console? Is your JSON proper one (I mean callback is executed)?

Comment: [{"name":"tgl_pemasukan","data":["2015-03-05","2015-03-06","2015-03-07"]},{"name":"pengeluaran","data":[null,700000,null]},{"name":"pemasukan","data":[50000,90000,50000]}] this my json data

Comment: Yes, I can see your image. Test your data with parser, for example [this one](http://json.parser.online.fr/) - for me it throws an error in number 9000 (some extra sign between there).

Comment: this now json, [{"name":"tgl_pemasukan","data":["2015-03-06","2015-03-07"]},{"name":"pengeluaran","data":[700000,0]},{"name":"pemasukan","data":[90000,50000]}]

Comment: function show_pendapatan_pengeluaran(){
            foreach ($data_detail->result() as $row) {
                $tgl_pemasukan['data'][] = $row->tgl_pemasukan;
                $pengeluaran['data'][] = $row->pengeluaran;
                $pemasukan['data'][] = $row->pemasukan;
            }
            $result = array();
            array_push($result,$tgl_pemasukan);
            array_push($result,$pengeluaran);
            array_push($result,$pemasukan);
            print json_encode($result,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
        
        }

Comment: Your second JSON looks fine. You still didn't answer my question: "Do you have any errors in the JS console"?

Comment: i'm sorry mr pawel, i cant read englis with good. yes i give a wrong "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"